# Novel Document Class crashes

Tags: books

Everyone.

I am new to LaTex, so I apologize if this has been answered before.  I am using TexWorks to write my novel.  It appears that the novel class is not working.  it crashes.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks,
ML

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice? Please add some more info in your first question to help us help you.

Comment: Which is the error? The same of your other question?

Comment: I am the author of the novel document class. Due to some change in another LaTeX package (only recently), novel now crashes. I have requested that CTAN remove novel, as I do not intend to keep modifying the code. Novel certainly did not crash before.

Comment: In the time period near when the OP asked this question, there was an update to another package, causing previously-good novel to crash for some users (not all). This issue was subsequently fixed with novel.